# Question about asympotic expansion of $\int_0^x t\sqrt{ln(t)} dt$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Question:
Find the constants $$a_0, a_1, a_2$$ in the asympotic expansion

$$\int_0^x t\sqrt{ln(t)} dt$$ = $a_0(x^2)(lnx)^\frac 12$ + $a_1\frac {x^2}{(lnx)^\frac 12}$ + $a_2\frac {x^2}{(lnx)^\frac 32}$ + ...

In what regime is this a useful asymptotic expansion? Justify your answer.

I'm confused about this last part, what does "In what regime" mean. Someone please help! Thank you!!

Comment: Have you determined the constants? If yes, have you checked convergence of the series?

Comment: "In what regime" is asking you to say when the given expansion is valid as an asymptotic series.  Is it valid when $x \to 0$?  Is it valid when $x \to \infty$?  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

It may be noticed that enacting the transformation $t = e^{-y}$ the desired integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x} t \, \sqrt{\ln(t)} \, dt &= i \, \int_{- \ln(x)}^{\infty} e^{- 2 y} \, \sqrt{y} \, dy \\
&= \frac{i}{2 \sqrt{2}} \, \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} , - \ln(x^{2}) \right)
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(x,a)$ is the incomplete gamma function. Also the transformation $u=2y$ was made. Now using the series expansion, for large argument,
$$\Gamma(a,t) \approx t^{a-1} \, e^{-t} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, (1-a)_{n}}{t^{n}}$$
the integral can be seen as
$$\int_{0}^{x} t \, \sqrt{\ln(t)} \, dt \approx \frac{x^{2}}{2} \, \sqrt{\ln(x)} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}}{\ln^{n}(x)}.$$
The desired coefficients may be obtained from this expansion. Note that
$(a)_{n}$ is Pochhammer's notation and is:
$$(a)_{n} = \frac{\Gamma(n+a)}{\Gamma(a)}.$$